# Loop through list operating on result and next value

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress

I have a sorted list of objects

```
l = sorted(['/path/to/1.obj', '/path/to/2.obj', '/path/to/3.obj', '/path/to/4.obj'])
```

I want to loop through the object performing an operation on them and using the result to preform the next operation.

For example

```
result1 = my_operation(l[0], l[1])
result2 = my_operation(result1, l[2])
resultFinal = my_operation(result2, l[3])
```

How can I do this in a list of an arbitrary length?

Comment: This really looks like a writer monad... https://nikgrozev.com/2013/12/10/monads-in-15-minutes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) does:

```py
from functools import reduce

def my_operation(total, value):
    return total + value

print(reduce(my_operation, [1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: Your example works but in practice I'm getting `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U10'), dtype('<U10')) -> dtype('<U10')`

Comment: Could you show your my_operation function ? The error seems indicating that it does not have the expected signature. What version of Python are you using ?

Comment: It's very long ... I think I see what's going on.  The list contains paths to images.  The result returned from the function is an image, so on the second iteration an image and a path get passed into the function when it expects 2 paths.  I think I just need to modify how my function works.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is a loop:

```
def op(a,b):
    return a*b

l = [1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 92]

k = op(*l[:2]) 
print(k)

for item in l[2:]:
    k = op(k, item)
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
2           # 1 * 2
8           #       * 4
56          #            * 7
672         #                * 12
61824       #                     * 92
```

Make sure your list has at least 2 elements and you should be fine.